# Computed property (SUM) In EF Core 5 model causes application to exit

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I am having a strange problem in my application.

Using EF Core 5, I have a SalesOrderItem Model:

```cs
public class SalesOrderItem
{
    public int SalesOrderItemId { get; set; }

    public int? Qty { get; set; }

    public decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }
    
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SalesOrderId")]
    public int SalesOrderId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public decimal LineTotal => (Qty == null ? 0 : Qty.Value) * (UnitPrice == null ? 0 : UnitPrice.Value); 
}
```

This model has a computed property which gets the line value.

I have a SalesOrder model. I want computed properties for gross, net and tax:

```cs
public class SalesOrder
{
    public int SalesOrderId { get; set; }

    public int VatCodeId { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<SalesOrderItem> SalesOrderItems { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public decimal? Net
    {
        get
        {
            if (SalesOrderItems == null)
                return null;

            return SalesOrderItems.Sum(p => p.LineTotal);
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public decimal? Tax
    {
        get
        {
            if (Net == null)
                return null;

            return (Net.Value * VatCode.Percentage) / 100;
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public decimal? Gross
    {
        get
        {
            if (Net == null || VatCode == null)
                return null;

            return Net.Value + Gross.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

This causes my application to exit on startup with no error in VS.

If I remove the property "Gross", then the application does not close.

Does anyone know why my "Gross" computed field is causing my app to crash?

I am using the following code which works when Gross is omitted:

```
var salesOrder = await _context.SalesOrder.Include(p => p.VatCode).Include(i => i.SalesOrderItems).SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.SalesOrderId == salesOrderId);
```

Apologies for the "Snippet". I could not paste the model into code without it breaking.

Comment: `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` is for columns whose values are computed by the database, not by your code. It means EF won't attempt to update them when the row is inserted or updated. If these are computed properties in your code that don't map to db columns use `[NotMapped]`.

Comment: Apologies. I changed them to [NotMapped] and it's the same problem so will update my question.

Comment: Are you running migrations or other database queries during startup?

Comment: No nothing like that. If I remove the "Gross" field, the page application starts without any issue and displays the expected data.

Comment: _Displays expected data_ mean that application executes some database operations to load "expected data" - that where issue is, can you show query you are using to load expected data.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code the controller calls.

Comment: You access `Gross` in `Gross`. This is a StackOverflowException. It's a simple typo, I think it's `Net.Value + Tax.Value`.

Comment: If this causes Visual Studio to crash, please submit a report to Microsoft.

Comment: Already done, JH. Thank you